# How do I bake/add material colors onto my UVmap?

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking, uv-image-editor, vertex-colors

I looked everywhere from tutorials to documents and either they only talk about texturing or they are doing the tutorial in 'blender render' when I need it in 'cycles render'.

I have a cube that is toon shaded red. And as you can see it is unwrapped to show the map. 
[image]

Now I would like to add the color that's on the cube onto the map.

As you can see at the bottom of the image that I created a new image called 'untitled'. Now the next step of baking the colors onto the map is where I become lost. Regardless of which 'Bake Type' that I used, I keep getting error messages like: No valid selected objects.

Everything looks selected to me. No, I am not new to Blender but I am new to color baking. Thank you for any help provided; I used a simple cube first before using other models I already created.

Answer (score 2):

Befor baking you need to open the Node editor and there add an image to bake to.

It is very important that this Image Texture node is selected before baking.

1: Open a node editor window.

2: Put a check against the Use Nodes option.

3: Add an Image Texture node.

4: Load the image that you want to bake to into the Image Texture node.

5: Before leaving the Node editor make sure that the Image Texture node is selected.

6: Hit that bake button.

[image]

Hope this helps some  :)