# Why does a Wave Texture not follow a rig?

Tags: texturing, rigging, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping

I'm rigging a simple character with a stripey texture and rigify rig.

Before rigging, if I move the geo, the texture moves with it, once I parent it to the rig the texture stays still while I move the armature, almost like it's projected.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a fix that doesn't mean UV unwrapping everything as the current setup looks fine for this character. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of the two states when in Pose mode? I am trying here, and my texture is still following my Suzanne even with the Object coordinate not specified to use the monkey. - seems I spoke too soon, deform follows but moving the whole armature doesn't.

Comment: If I change to Generated coordinate instead, the wave texture follows correctly. I wonder if you have found a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using 'Object' as your 'texture coords' but you have no 'object' selected in the field box. You really should be unwrapping and using 'UV' coords instead.

Comment: I had a feeling I wouldn't be able to avoid UVing! Thanks, setting the Object didn't work either but in the end I baked the textures and applied them which worked with helpful info from these posts too. Thanks again. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95328/cycles-baking-diffuse-result-is-always-black

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92665/how-do-i-bake-add-material-colors-onto-my-uvmap