# Generate Color-Map in blender

Tags: texturing, uv

here is what I do right now: I create an image and fill it with some colors like so:

[image: image with color rects]

then I unwrap my mesh so that every face gets the color I want it to have.

However I don't like this workflow at all, I would prefer it, if I could just select colors for the faces in blender and then blender automatically generates a color map.

Somone knows if this is possible? It must be an image so I can import it to my game engine

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to select each face, assign it a color and bake that? By the time you're done, you have easily created a new material for each face. Use groups to coordinate them, so you only need to change the color of the material.

Comment: Related: [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/516/78972) and [How do I bake/add material colors onto my UVmap?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/92665/78972)